# Passing Guid to stored procedure throws Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '@Id'.'

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Owner].GetById
    @LanguageCode CHAR(5) = 'en-us', 
    @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ...
    WHERE LanguageCode = @LanguageCode
      AND Id = @Id;
END
```

And I am trying something like this to call the stored procedure using Entity Framework Core:

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter ("@LangaugeCode", "en-us");
var param2 = new SqlParameter ("@Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
param2.Value = Guid.Parse("0ec0d169-0a4f-4458-a48b-729e1bb0fea9");

var context = new localContext(); // Auto-generated class for DB first approach
var manufacturers= context.Owner.FromSqlRaw($"EXEC Owner.GetById 
@LanguageCode, @Id", param1, param2).ToList();
```

It's throwing an error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '@Id'.'

Is it happening because of the Guid can not be passed as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER or is it a formatting issue?

Comment: yeah, the syntax is definitely correct. I have a web api - that works fine with that same stored proc but from console app, its throwing that exception.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `FromSqlRaw($"EXEC Manufacturer.GetById ", param1, param2)` or at least a comma between the named parameters: `@LanguageCode, @Id`

Comment: Sorry, comma was originally there. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need one of :

```
var p1 = "en-us";
var p2 = Guid.Parse("0ec0d169-0a4f-4458-a48b-729e1bb0fea9");

var owners= context.Owner.FromSqlRaw(
  "Owner.GetById {0}, {1}",
  p1, 
  p2
}.ToList();

var owners= context.Owner.FromSqlInterpolated(
  $"Owner.GetById {p1}, {p2}").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the query from

```
FromSqlRaw($"EXEC Owner.GetById @LanguageCode @Id", param1, param2).ToList();
```

To:

```
FromSqlRaw($"EXEC Owner.GetById {0}, {1}", param1, param2).ToList();
```

Comment: It throws:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier'

Comment: So you're passing in a `Int` and its expecting a `GUID`? Double check the parameter values you're passing in

Comment: Because its RAW it doesn't support SqlParameters, you'd need to use `param1.value` , `param2.value` and CAST them if you need to be explicit, eg: `Convert.ToInt()`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this. You do not need `EXEC` .

```
FromSqlRaw($"Owner.GetById {0}, {1}", p1, p2)
```

Comment: Even though it looks logical but didn't work in my case